# Write Json to server endpoint

Tags: c#, json, amazon-ec2, json.net, endpoint

I have an Ubuntu server instance running in Amazon EC2.
I want to write json to an endpoint in that url, for instance "http://myurl/myendpoint".
How do I create this endpoint and how do I write json to it with C#?

Comment: You want to call this endpoint from c# application? Or you want to create web api using c# and deploy in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Information you gave are too scarse. What exactly are you tryingt to achieve? Do you have a REST API deployed on that server? If not, then you probably want to create a REST Api. You can use it to create a mechanism that will be able to handle requests/responses.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api